# Absolute position div not working css

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element that is relatively positioned. I also have two absolutely positioned child elements that I want in respective corners (top left and top right). However, both of these elements won't show up in the DOM. I have explicit heights and width on both of these elements. I also tried changing the `z-index` of both elements to no avail.

Here is the markup and css:

```css
.first_customer, .all_customer {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner > * {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #fad63a;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 85%;
}

.inner > h4 {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.inner > h6 {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.inner > p {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.topleftcorner, .toprightcorner {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.topleftcorner {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_customer">
    <div class="topleftcorner"></div>
    <div class="toprightcorner"></div>

    <div class="inner">
        <h4>New Customers</h4>
        <h6>$10 Gift</h6>
        <p>Dry Cleaning</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried putting text in the DIV's? I tested exactly what you have except for the fact that I added the words "hi" and "hello" in each of the two top-corner divs. the top left one seems fine, but your top right one looks like it could use some work.

Comment: I never set a background color...

Comment: You mentioned only for ".topleftcorner" but not defined yet for ".toprightcorner" corner coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

it's working already. I just added background color and position right div.

```css
.first_customer,.all_customer{
 flex: 1 1 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.inner{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner > *{
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #fad63a;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;

}

.inner > h4{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inner > h6{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inner > p{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.topleftcorner,.toprightcorner{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.topleftcorner{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.toprightcorner {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_customer">

  <div class="topleftcorner"></div>
  <div class="toprightcorner"></div>

  <div class="inner">
    <h4>New Customers</h4>
    <h6>$10 Gift</h6>
    <p>Dry Cleaning</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there , need some changes for right corner.

```css
.first_customer,.all_customer{
 flex: 1 1 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}

.inner{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner > *{
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #fad63a;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;

}

.inner > h4{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inner > h6{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.inner > p{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.topleftcorner,.toprightcorner{
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
}

.topleftcorner{
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.toprightcorner{
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_customer">

  <div class="topleftcorner"></div>
  <div class="toprightcorner"></div>

  <div class="inner">
    <h4>New Customers</h4>
    <h6>$10 Gift</h6>
    <p>Dry Cleaning</p>
  </div>

</div>
```